# Android Studio rendering errors, while the app works correctly

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio I used a SeekBar  from external source. 
The app *works correctly*, but I still get two Rendering errors:

> 1. "Failed to find style 'discreteSeekBarStyle' in current theme"
> 2. "Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?  Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references."

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the app works fine maybe you can fix it just restarting Android Studio. 
It append to me very often and I solve it just restarting Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I managed to solve it by adding:

```
<item name="discreteSeekBarStyle">@style/Widget.DiscreteSeekBar</item>
```

to `AppTheme` style (my theme) in `styles.xml`.

Also, from [AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar](https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar) GitHub repo:

> You can also use the attribute **discreteSeekBarStyle** on your themes with a custom Style to be applied to all the DiscreteSeekBars on your app/activity/fragment/whatever.